# When to use a Custom ModelBinder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

In the past few days, I’ve been brushing up my MVC skills on `Custom ModelBinders` . Simply put, I’ve never had the chance to create one because I never met a scenario that would qualify or require me to create a custom ModelBinder.

I’ve seen and read many examples on `How to...`but what I haven’t seen are relevant examples on `Why to...`

Perhaps I’m not looking hard enough.

Consider one example I found where the programmer had the following `ViewModel`:

```
public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

The View is strongly typed on the `HomeViewModel` and it has 3 additional fields like so:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
    Day: <input id="Day" name="Day" value="" type="text" />
    Month: <input id="Month" name="Month" value="" type="text" />
    Year: <input id="Year" name="Year" value="" type="text" />

    <input id="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The programmer decides to create a Custom `ModelBinder` so that when the `<form>` is submitted, the 3 fields are captured and nicely placed/formatted inside the `Date` property of the `HomeViewModel`.

I understand the idea but what I don’t understand is why go thru all the trouble of creating a custom ModelBinding and more importantly, not forget to register it inside the Application_Start() when instead, I could simply modify the `HomeViewModel` by adding 3 fields and capture everything inside the Date property like so:

```
public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }

        public string Date 
        { 
            get { return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", this.Day, this.Month, this.Year);}
        }
    }
```

(Needless to say, I’d have to modify my `<form>` but this is trivial...)

Unless I’m missing something, there is got to be a better reason why people go the extra mile to create custom ModelBinders.

If anyone could share thoughts or ideas that would warrants the creation of a Custom ModelBinder, I’d be happy to hear about it.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons I have used custom model binders

here is an example of one I have used in the past

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/519301/Automatic-Encryption-of-Secure-Form-Field-Data

The other is if you want to bind to interfaces and do late time binding on the concretion, Mvc doesn't support that out of the box, you can write a model binder to do it though

Comment: Yes, I can see the need for the HtmlHelper to encrypt the value in the hidden field but if my hidden field *Name* property matches the name of a property defined in my ViewModel, then there’s no particular need for the custom ModelBinder. All that is needed, upon submit, is a Server Side method that would decrypt the value currently stored in the ViewModel’s property no? By the way, thanks for the reply.